# Change pointer line style

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I am creating gauge using this example, but I have to change pointer style.
Is it possible to change pointer style like this?

[image]

```
Chart.Type.extend({
      //Passing in a name registers this chart in the Chart namespace
      name: "Gauge",
      //Providing a defaults will also register the deafults in the chart namespace
      defaults : defaultConfig,


      initialize:  function(data){
          //Declare segments as a static property to prevent inheriting across the Chart type prototype
          this.segments = [];
          var pointerDotRadius = helpers.min([this.chart.width,this.chart.height])/50;
          this.outerRadius = (helpers.min([this.chart.width,this.chart.height]) - this.options.segmentStrokeWidth/2)/2;
          this.SegmentArc = Chart.Arc.extend({
              ctx : this.chart.ctx,
              x : this.chart.width/2,
              y : this.chart.height - pointerDotRadius
          });
```

All code:
[jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/teduxijipi/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar looking meter chart using the RGraph ( https://www.rgraph.net ) software in the download archive:

```
demos/meter-needle.html
```

And here's the code:

```
    var meter = new RGraph.Meter({
        id: 'cvs',
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 75,
        options: {
            linewidthSegments: 20,
            strokestyle: 'white',
            segmentRadiusStart: 105,
            border: 0,
            tickmarksSmallNum: 0,
            tickmarksBigNum: 0,
            needleRadius: 205,
            labels: false,
            centerpinFill: 'black',
            colorsRanges: [
                [0, 30, '#FFC900'],
                [30, 60, '#8FCE21'],
                [60, 100, '#0094DA']
            ]
        }
    }).draw();
```

Comment: FWIW When I release the new version the pointer in the example will change to that that more closely resembles the picture.